# Embedding GitHub-Pages content without using iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, github-pages

My `VueJS` application usually contains links to other pages (documentations) but it would be desirable to display the documentation content inside my page without the users having to leave for another page. Some of them are **hosted on GitHub pages** and although I could embed them into my app via `iframe`, I can't get rid of the feeling that there must be a **more elegant way to display the information** from the external documentation.

All I can think of is to write some kind of HTML parser on top of `jssoup`, however, this seems to be a very tightly coupled approach to the target page that could potentially require adjustments whenever the structure of the target page changes..

Is there any potential approach that I could consider to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this topic is obsolete. Turns out that one could use iFrames or crawl the contents from which both solutions aren't very pretty and infeasible in general.